# Java ant build.xml with .jar lib compiles fine but fails on execute

Tags: java, jar, ant

I'm a student learning to create an ant build file, I have some .java source files in /src, and a .jar library (json.jar) in /lib. I've included the .jar in the classpath in for javac in the build.xml and it compiles fine, but fails on execute:

```
     [echo] command line execute: java -cp classes:lib/json.jar Main
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONString
 [java]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1007)
 [java]     at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
 [java]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
 [java]     at Main.main(Unknown Source)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONString
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
 [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
 [java]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
 [java]     ... 10 more
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

here is my build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Ant-Test" default="targets" basedir=".">
    <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
    <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
    <property name="build" location="classes" />
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="lib" value="lib" />
    <property name="user" value="${env.USERNAME}"/>

    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${build}"/>
        <pathelement path="lib/json.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="targets">
        <echo message="Targets are clean, prepare, build, execute, and targets"/>
    </target>

    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${build}"/>
    </path>

    <!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
    <target name="prepare">
        <mkdir dir="${build}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
    <target name="build" depends="prepare">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" includeantruntime="false" destdir="${build}" classpath="lib/json.jar">
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="execute" depends="build" description="Run the program">
        <echo message="command line execute: java -cp classes:lib/json.jar Main" />
        <java classname="Main" fork="yes">
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

I'm not sure what else to try, any help is appreciated!

Comment: That classpath issue. what is the project directory structure? Is `build` and `lib` directories at same level?

Comment: @Rao yes, they're both in the root directory.

Comment: It looks like you are using Java 9. Could you try `<jvmarg value="--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM"/>` inside the `<java>` element?